# what is the maximum number of elements that driver.find_elements can get in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I use `driver.find_elements` to get a list of elements that match the condition in Python and Selenium. If the page has many elements that match the condition of find_elements. What is limit of find_elements? In other words, what is the maximum number of elements that driver.find_elements can get in Selenium? If the page has more elements that the maximum number of elements that driver.find_elements can get, what is gonna happen? Will it throw an exception or only return elements that are within the limit?

Answer (score 0):

I think is 5000, when the element is more than 5000, it will only get the first 5000.